Getting the character controller to stick to the ground?
I got this to work but really simply by using a Raycast and checking for the angle then pushing the player down with verticalVelocity. But then it prevents the player from jumping when moving up or down stairs, and even though I added a clause for that with if (!Input("Jump)") and a groundedTimer of 0.3f seconds, there’s still really inconsistent movement.
Like at the very start of the scene, debugging shows that the player is NOT grounded, and my animation reflects that because the falling animation plays. Adding isGrounded = true; to Start() works but that doesn’t seem like a good solution. I’m just trying to get the player to stick to every surface it’s moving on but still be able to jump normally. Running down stairs makes my player run into the air, then fall down.
I also don’t know how a Raycast or SphereCast will work on different surfaces like rough terrain, rounded objects, etc, or at the bottom of stairs/slopes, etc, where the Raycast will no longer work. But replacing it with a SphereCast makes it work on the edges of objects which shouldn’t happen. Using layers has been inconsistent so far, unless I add invisible colliders to every single object with a certain layer to prevent those edge cases, but I don’t know if that’s smart either.
I can’t find any kind of relevant and helpful information or resources/tutorials. Is there nothing out there with better insight on how to handle this?
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, out RaycastHit hit, 1.3f))
{
    float angle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, hit.normal);

    if (angle > 0.1f)
    {
        hitNormal = hit.normal;
        velocity.y = -15f; // Make the player snap to/stay on the ground
    }
    else
    {
        hitNormal = Vector3.up;
    }
}
else
{
    hitNormal = Vector3.up;
}

if (!isGrounded)
{
    Debug.Log(isGrounded);
}

Edit: I think I seemed to fix the jumping issue, but when jumping up the staircase, the jump length is greatly shortened which I think makes since since you're jumping uphill. But at the bottom of the stairs/slope/any angled surface, the Raycast stops hitting so isGrounded turns false and the player bounces repeatedly.

why cant you jump when moving up/down stairs? your jump force should overpower the gravity in your world, no need for 'if !jump', if the issue is that your character can't tell if you are grounded while on stairs, simply add more raycasting to the left most and right most side of your player sprite, you could also add a raycast in the center for spherical pbjects

So my default verticalVelocity when grounded is -2f (and when falling), and so when I am on a slope, I set the verticalVelocity to something like -10f or -15f to keep the isGrounded from constantly going from false, true, false, true, etc. As a result, the jumping is so inconsistent and sometimes jumping does not work, especially going down the slope or even basic stairs.

@derHugo yeah sorry, I added my code. It's very simple. Basically jumping doesn't work at all, however isGrounded now works perfectly and I don't bounce down stairs anymore. But at the bottom of the stairs, my player bounces since the Raycast stops hitting. SphereCast makes it worse on the corners of objects.

why don't you remember what the last hit was ... as long as it was stairs you apply the heavy down force to stick to them .. as soon as the stairs are over you deactivate this and have normal ground again ... or do you have stairs ending mid air?

That's a good idea. However, what if the angled surface is not stairs, but more like terrain? If I jump onto the bottom of the terrain, the ray won't hit so the code will never run. but if I replace it with a sphere, even if the radius is smaller than the player capsule, it will hit edges and try to run the code which causes very abnormal behiavour, if that makes sense

sounds like changing the velocity is trying to cure the symptom and not the illness. could lead to convoluted and badly maintainable code

I've tried using a combo of Vector3.Cross and Vector3.Angle with my Raycast and with that, manipulate the actual .Move() of the controller without having more than one call to .move() in my code, but so far it's been causing several bugs I can't debug like the player auto flying to the top of a slope, etc. Ik velocity.y method is not great, but I haven't found an online solution or even hint in 1.5+ months
